# POSBox image in a raspberry pi3, how does it work with an HDMI screen?

Tags: odoo

I installed the POSBox image in a raspberry pi3, everything worked great, now I would like to use that rp as a graphic POS and connect some HDMI screen and a printer to it..

I could see that there is no graphic interface installed by default in the POSBox image.
shoulod I install a graphic interface on the raspberry pi3?

Thanks in advance!